# Nestjs: How to remove particular app from nestjs monorepo with nest/cli

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

Is there way to remove particular app in nestjs monorepo using `nest/cli`? I couldn't find it from the documentation and dev forum.

Answer (score 11):

The CLI doesn't have a remove command for sub-apps. You'd need to `rm -rf apps/<sub-app>` and modify the `nest-cli.json` to remove the sub-app options from there